# Getting two rows in output in bigquery if using case

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When i m running this query giving result in two different rows of same date one contains zero other contains events count????
    How to solve this, any help will be really appreciated!

```
     (Select 
   distinct(case 
  when event_text = 'poll_vote' THEN device_id Else 0 END) as 
    pollvote,event_date from
  (Select event_date,event_text,count(distinct users) as device_id from
   (SELECT event.name as event_text,  ( user.value.value.string_value) 
    AS users,

    CAST(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), 
    INTERVAL 330 MINUTE) AS date) AS event_date
  FROM
       `dataset.tablename`,
      UNNEST(event_dim) AS event,
      UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) AS user
     where
         user.key="context_device_id" 
      GROUP BY
         event_date,event_text,users)
      GROUP BY
         event_text,event_date))
```

[image: see the output image]

Comment: I would suggest that you simplify and format the query.

Comment: Simplified the query @Gordon Linoff

Comment: If you want one row per `event_date`, then that should be the only column in the `group by`.  It is entirely unclear what your intended result is, because the query is doing exactly what the query is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Using ‘GROUP BY’ for event_date only should give you only one column as you wanted. Here are some of the [GROUP BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group-by-clause) examples.